# IMAP - difference between msgno and uid?

Tags: php, imap

What is the difference between msgno and uid? It looks like they always are the same even if msgs are deleted!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-uid.php:

This function returns the UID for the given message sequence number. **An UID is a unique identifier that will not change over time while a message sequence number may change whenever the content of the mailbox changes.**

Comment: When I delete msgs the uid changes and is always the same as msgno when retrieving data with `imap_fetch_overview()`

Comment: Have you tried deleting a message and re-fetching on the same session?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, uid is always the same as msgno and message_id

The worst it's that when i delete messages on the mail server, msgno and UID are **reattributed** in the order of arrival.

I have make a little script which fetch mails with imap_search and imap_overview to get headers, i use imap_uid($this->GetConnection(),$msgno); to force get the UID from the MSGNO and here the result :

echo "MSGNO : $msgno  UID : $overview->uid  UIDBYNO : ". $mbox->GetUidByNum($msgno)."
";

MSGNO : 851 UID : 851 UIDBYNO : 851
MSGNO : 852 UID : 852 UIDBYNO : 852
MSGNO : 853 UID : 853 UIDBYNO : 853
MSGNO : 854 UID : 854 UIDBYNO : 854
MSGNO : 855 UID : 855 UIDBYNO : 855
MSGNO : 856 UID : 856 UIDBYNO : 856
MSGNO : 857 UID : 857 UIDBYNO : 857

So 
1) uid isn't unique
2) msgno is always the same as uid

Maybe the mailserver doesn't respect the RFC !

Comment: Maybe you'd better test that without a client library, to be sure the server is at fault, not the client library. Telnet to the server's port 143, then say "a login maypeur foo" (that's login and password), "b select inbox" and "c fetch 1:* uid".

Comment: It won't work if one uses php imap to connect to a POP3 server, because POP3 apparently does not use/support proper UIDs. That was my problem anyways

Comment: try moving emails from one mailbox to another, then the numbers will change. :)